# How to change legend title in ggplot2 if "labs(fill=)" doesn't work?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I plotted three graphs using *ggplot2*, when they are displayed the legend title is `colour`, I tried:

```
+labs(fill="Temperature")
```

However after running the script there are no changes in the plots, as example I leave the following part of the script:

```
p <- ggplot(data_x, aes(Temp, group=1)) + geom_line(aes(y=X18, color="18°C"), size = 1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=X20, color="20°C"), size=1) + geom_line(aes(y=X25, color = "25°C"), size=1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=X27, color = "27°C"), size=1) + geom_line(aes(y=X30, color="30°C"), size=1) + theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0), labels= c("Day 1-2", "Day 3-4", "Day 5-6", "Day 7-8", "Day 9-10")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 8) + ggtitle("GPP") +theme (plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  xlab("Recording day") + ylab("Dissolved oxygen mg/L/s")+labs(fill ="Temperature")
```

Which other forms to change the legend title are possible?

Comment: I also tried guides() and scale_fill_discrete()

Comment: Try `labs(color = ...`. There is no fill legend as you are mapping on `color`.